# String validation in CodeIgniter using callback rules

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation

I want to check if a string is valid or invalid using CodeIgniter's Form Validation library.

If the input string has 9 numbers + 1 character in this set: `[xXvV]` or the string is empty, it is considered as valid. (e.g.: "123456789X", "987654321v", ""). I implemented a callback rule using `preg_match()` to no avail.

Setting rules in my controller:

```php
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nic', 'NIC', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_checkNIC');
```

And here's my callback function:

```php
public function checkNIC($nic){
        $reg = '/^(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)[xXvV]$/';

        if(preg_match($reg, $nic) || $nic == '') {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('checkNIC', 'The NIC is not valid');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please be more specific. How it's not working? any errors? Where did you define the callback? In the same controller?

Comment: I defined the callback in the same controller.

Comment: How do you say it is failing? Does the callback gets called?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your **controller** class where you're doing the validation. Or if you want to put it somewhere else, make sure it's [callable](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule):

```
public function checkNIC($nic)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('checkNIC', 'The NIC is not valid');

    return $nic === '' || (bool) preg_match('/^\d{9}[xXvV]$/', $nic);
}
```

Have a look:
https://3v4l.org/X3DhC

Comment: Could you please inspect the output of `checkNIC('fdg')` and `checkNIC('123456789X')`? Have a look: https://3v4l.org/X3DhC